# Multiple plot controlled by the same popupmenu in GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have this code, where I have a popupmenu for the user to decide the type of plot to be displayed in axes 1 and 2. The plots should only be visible if the checkmark is activated. If the checkmark is activated the plot should update if the popupmenu value is changed. So far it is working fine for the first plot. But I get a error code: "Function with duplicate name "myPlotFcn" cannot be defined." Do I have to define a new "myPlotFcn" for every plot, or is there a smoother way to control multiple (~50) plot from the same popupmenu? Here is my code:

```
% --- Executes on selection change in popupmenu1.
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
myPlotFcn(handles);
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
% --- Executes on button press in checkbox1.
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    myPlotFcn(handles);        
function myPlotFcn(handles)
    isChecked = get(handles.checkbox1,'value');
    if(isChecked)
        contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
        popupmenu1value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
        switch popupmenu1value
            case 'Raw CD [mdeg]'
                rawdata=handles.rawdata;
                x1=rawdata{1,2}(:,1);
                cd1raw=(rawdata{1,2}(:,2)-rawdata{1,1}(:,2));%sample-buffer
                cd1raw=cd1raw-cd1raw(1,1); %normalize to y=0 at 250 nm
                CD=cd1raw;
                ht1=rawdata{1,2}(:,3);                             
        %hold( handles.axes1, 'on' )
                handles.plotCD1 = plot(x1,CD,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes1);
        %hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )
                handles.plotHT1 = plot(x1,ht1,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);
                guidata(handles.plotCD1,handles);
                guidata(handles.plotHT1,handles);
              case 'Molar ellipticity [deg cm^2 dmol^-1]'
                  mg_ml_Conc=handles.mg_ml_Conc;
                  Length=handles.Length;
                  Mass=handles.Mass;
                  rawdata=handles.rawdata;
                  x1=rawdata{1,2}(:,1);
                  cd1raw=(rawdata{1,2}(:,2)-rawdata{1,1}(:,2));%sample-buffer
                  cd1raw=cd1raw-cd1raw(1,1); %normalize to y=0 at 250 nm   
                  CD=((cd1raw*Mass(1,1))/(10*Length(1,1)*mg_ml_Conc(1,1)));
                  %molar ellipticity=cdraw*mw/(10*cell-length(cm)*concentration(mg/ml))
                  ht1=rawdata{1,2}(:,3);
          %hold( handles.axes1, 'on' )
                  handles.plotCD1 = plot(x1,CD,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes1);
          %hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )
                  handles.plotHT1 = plot(x1,ht1,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);         
                  guidata(handles.plotCD1,handles);
                  guidata(handles.plotHT1,handles);
              case 'Mean residue ellipticity [deg cm^2 dmol^-1 residue^-1]'
                  Length=handles.Length;
                  mg_ml_Conc=handles.mg_ml_Conc;
                  Mass=handles.Mass;
                  Peptide=handles.Peptide;
                  rawdata=handles.rawdata;
                  x1=rawdata{1,2}(:,1);
                  cd1raw=(rawdata{1,2}(:,2)-rawdata{1,1}(:,2));%sample-buffer
                  cd1raw=cd1raw-cd1raw(1,1); %normalize to y=0 at 250 nm 
                  CD=(cd1raw/1000*100)/(Length(1,1)*mg_ml_Conc(1,1)/Mass(1,1)*Peptide(1,1));
                  %Normalized data:(abscorrected/1000*100)/(pathlength*concentration(mg/ml)/Mw*no. of peptidebonds)
                  ht1=rawdata{1,2}(:,3);
               %hold( handles.axes1, 'on' )
                  handles.plotCD1 = plot(x1,CD,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes1);         
               %hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )
                  handles.plotHT1 = plot(x1,ht1,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);
                  guidata(handles.plotCD1,handles);
                  guidata(handles.plotHT1,handles);
             end
             else     
               if ~isempty(handles.plotCD1)
                  delete(handles.plotCD1)
                  ~isempty(handles.plotHT1)  
                  delete(handles.plotHT1)
                  set(handles.text2, 'BackgroundColor', [0.94 0.94 0.94]);
             end    
      end
% --- Executes on button press in checkbox3.
function checkbox3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
myPlotFcn(handles);        
function myPlotFcn(handles)
    isChecked = get(handles.checkbox3,'value');
    if(isChecked)
        contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
        popupmenu1value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
        switch popupmenu1value
            case 'Raw CD [mdeg]'
                rawdata=handles.rawdata;
                x1=rawdata{1,2}(:,1);
                cd1raw=(rawdata{1,2}(:,2)-rawdata{1,1}(:,2));%sample-buffer
                cd1raw=cd1raw-cd1raw(1,1); %normalize to y=0 at 250 nm
                CD=cd1raw;
                ht1=rawdata{1,2}(:,3);                             
        %hold( handles.axes1, 'on' )
                handles.plotCD1Adj = plot(x1,CD,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes1);
        %hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )
                handles.plotHT1Adj = plot(x1,ht1,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);
                guidata(handles.plotCD1Adj,handles);
                guidata(handles.plotHT1Adj,handles);
              case 'Molar ellipticity [deg cm^2 dmol^-1]'
  ... and so on similar to the above checkbox, but with different x,y values
```

I guess the code is a bit clumsy so any suggestion for a more clean code which will contain 50 checkboxes is highly appreciated. THANKS.

Comment: Matlab is right... Why you use the same name for different functions? How you want to debug it, for example...? And why you don't `end` your functions? it's really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have more or less the same code for every 'version' of myPlotFcn you need with the exception of a few values and - in your example - the checkbox variable to be checked, then write this function just ONCE. (Matlab will also be happier as it will know which function you want to call!)

Use additional input variables to myPlotFcn to differentiate the calls - a string for the checkbox to get the value of, any x,y values that the code will require. This will involve some rewriting of the existing code to accept variables where hard values currently exist, but it will result in much cleaner code that scales to many checkboxes in a much simpler fashion than your approach thus far.

Each checkbox callback function then just needs to call this single myPlotFcn with the correct set of additional variables.

Comment: Hey etmuse. Thanks a lot for your answer. Sorry but I am very new in matlab coding. By "the checkbox variable to be checked, then write this function just ONCE" do you mean call all the checkbox values as one parameter and then plot based on the values in a loop function?

Comment: write one function that is called myPlotFcn as you have already done. Instead of hard coding in the values for x,y and the name of which checkbox to look at to make sure it is checked, write those with variables instead. (Any other values that change depending on the checkbox do the same for those.)
So you'd end up with myPlotFcn(handles,checkboxname,x,y) as your function. 
In each callback function (eg checkbox1_Callback, checkbox3_Callback shown above) you'd then call myPlotFcn(handles,'checkbox1',3,5) or whatever.

Comment: Hi etmuse. First of all thanks a lot for spending the time trying to help me out. However, I don't have the matlab knowledge to carry out your suggestion, which is a shame because it sounded very cool. I did however try a different approach in case you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054269/display-selected-plots-in-gui-axes